# Which HTTP and WebDav status **MUST NOT** include message body?

Tags: http

I already know 204 and 205 **MUST NOT** include message body.

any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only exceptions are 1xx, 204 and 304 (and HEAD responses). See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-23.html#message.body.length.

Also: you need to be aware of the difference between "does not have a message body" and "message body must be empty".

Comment: Thanks! What I want to know is status whose "message body must be empty", because I want to avoid sending a response body with such status. And I have one more question: RFC 2616 says 205 MUST NOT include an entity. Does it not mean that 205 MUST NOT include message body?

Comment: Please stop looking at RFC 2616 -- the relevant description is in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-23.html#status.205

Comment: Wow, draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-23 says 205 MUST send a message body of zero length so the message MUST contain "Content-Length: 0". Does it mean that we must not use transfer-encoding, which does not allow Content-Length header, with 205? @JulianReschke

Comment: npcode: good catch. In general, if you find issues like these please send back to the httpbis mailing list.